# How to silence "Unapproved Verbs" warning message after importing module?

Tags: powershell

I'm aware this topic has been answered quite a few times already, however, no solutions seem to work for me. When I use the following command:

```
Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector
```

AND any/every combination of the following suggested solutions appended to the end of that command:

```
-DisableNameChecking
-WarningAction SilentlyContinue
-WarningAction Ignore
3>$null
| Out-Null
```

I get the following error message every single time:

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'tmp_ivxfpxoe.td2' include unapproved verbs
that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the 
Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Odd. `Import-Module -WarningAction SilentlyContinue` should do the trick. What version of PowerShell is this? (please show output from `$PSVersionTable`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen PSVersion 5.1.14409.1018 ...... Let me know if you need any more information from $PSVersionTable